# Сколько разметок необходимо верстать

Tags: android, android-layout

Так сколько же макетов необходимо верстать, чтобы приложение поддерживало планшеты 7 и 9-10 дюймов?

На каком-то ресурсе прочитал что кроме обычного layout достаточно сверстать layout-sw600dp и layout-sw720dp. Но на других ресурсах пишут что нужно layout-sw600dp и layout-sw820dp. 720 или 820?

Answer (score 2):

Если все сделать грамотно: то есть использовать в разметке только `dp` - *density pixel*, а используемые битмапы/иконки правильно смасштабировать то достаточно одной, единственной разметки в основном `layout`

Comment: У меня есть разметка для телефонов, но на планшете она выглядит не очень. Все располагается по центру, а вокруг пустоты большие. Поэтому и возник вопрос 720 или 820? В ответе @pavlofff пишет что 620 и 820

Comment: Покажите свою разметку (модифицируйте вопрос или задайте новый)

Comment: Вопрос то общего характера я не только конкретно для своей разметки спрашиваю, а вообще как обычно делают?

Comment: В общем я уже ответил

Answer (score 1):

Дополнительные разметки нужны, когда требуется менять компоновку (расположение и/или количество виджетов), а когда

> Все располагается по центру, а вокруг пустоты большие

Можно задать размеры пропорционально экрану и доп. разметок не понадобиться.
Также можно задать размеры виджетов с помощью dimens ресурсов, разложенных по соответствующим папкам.

Comment: А как задать размеры пропорционально экрану? У меня всего почти указаны размеры в dp. Или через dimens ресурсы как указать? Можете дать ссылку на какой-то пример

Comment: Не работал никогда с Dimens ресурсами. Подскажите пожалуйста какие папки нужно создать для dimens ресурсов. values-sw620dp типа таких?

Comment: Кажется понял. Создать такие же папки типа values-sw620dp, values-sw720dp и в них файлы dimens.xml с соответствующими размерами для каждого экрана.

Comment: (facepalm).....

Comment: @Webeus - это к вопросу "общего характера". Разный контент масштабируется по разному. Оптимальный вариант выбирается по конкретной задаче. Кроме конкретной ширины/высоты есть относительные wrapcontent, mathparent, есть [веса](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) , [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) с процентами и прочей прелестью, наконец

Comment: У меня последний вопрос остался. Вот для в папке values создал файл dimens.xml И прописал там все разметки. Теперь хочу создать папку values-sw600dp и в нем в файле dimens.xml прописать уже другие значения ресурсов. Вот как это можно визуально увидеть в студии если я буду изменять значения в файле dimens.xml как это выглядит на устройстве с диагональю 7 дюймов? Пытаюсь выбрать какое-нибудь устройство в диагональю 7 или 10 дюймов, но ничего не происходит